# Show message in form with only html

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Im creating a form and in this form I want a message to be displayed when the user clicks the submit button. Can this be done without php?

Comment: Without php - use javascript.

Comment: What kind of message do you want to display? A message in an alert box? Or just simply display a message in a custom div?
If you want to display an alert box you can do it like this:
`<input type="submit" onclick="alert('The submit button was pressed'); return false;">`

Comment: Thanks! :D @pappfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `input` element with `type="submit"`, consider using a normal button with an `onclick` attribute. Do not specify any `action` attribute for the `<form>` element.

```
<form>
  <input id="usn" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <input id="psw" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" onsubmit="myFunction()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var username = "The username you entered is: " + document.getElementById('usn').value + ". ";
    var password = "The password you entered is: " + document.getElementById('psw').value + ". ";
    alert(username + password);
  }
</script>
```